# Use Multiple Services for Singleton in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using the repository method for a data access class. So the constructor looks something like this:

```
public class MongoDbUnitOfWork : IMongoDbUnitOfWork 
{

    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public MongoDbUnitOfWork(ILogger logger, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config

        //do other stuff here, create database connection, etc.
    }

}

public interface IMongoDbUnitOfWork
{
    // various methods go in here
}
```

The key thing is that the constructor relies on the fact that 2 services are parsed to it.

Then in startup.cs I tried to do the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IMongoDbUnitOfWork>(sp =>
    {
        var logger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
        var config = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
        return new MongoDbUnitOfWork(logger, config);
    });

    //add other services 

}
```

This compiled but did not work when I tried to run an API route through a controller. I got an error stating:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'NamespaceDetailsHere.IMongoDbUnitOfWork' while attempting to activate 'NamespaceDetailsHere.Controllersv1.TestController'.
```

Then I ran a little Debug.WriteLine() script in startup.cs to see whether the ILogger and IConfiguration services existed. They did. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Have you tried just adding all your services like:
services.AddSingleton<IMongoDbUnitOfWork,MongoDbUnitOfWork>();
services.AddSingleton<ILogger,LoggerImpl>();
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration ,ConfigImpl>();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET Core service container will automatically resolve the services dependencies that are injected through the constructor, so you dont need the action configuration at all. When the service is constructed, any dependencies in the constructor are automatically required (as you're able to see with the exception).

Simply register your services with

```
services.AddSingleton<IMongoDbUnitOfWork, MongoDbUnitOfWork>();
```